# How do I display serial monitor on LCD keypad shield?

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I want to be able to display what I am seeing on the serial monitor onto the LCD keypad shield I have connected to my Arduino UNO. Can someone possibly write the the code ontop of this for me?
I'm very new to coding so I apologies if it's hard for anyone to understand what i'm asking for.

```
int ledPin = 13; // LED is attached to digital pin 13
int x = 0; // variable to be updated by the interrupt

//variables to keep track of the timing of recent interrupts
unsigned long button_time = 0;  
unsigned long last_button_time = 0; 

void setup() {                
  //enable interrupt 0 which uses pin 2
  //jump to the increment function on falling edge
  attachInterrupt(0, increment, FALLING);
  Serial.begin(9600);  //turn on serial communication
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(500); //pretend to be doing something useful
  Serial.println(x, DEC); //print x to serial monitor
}

// Interrupt service routine for interrupt 0
void increment() {
  button_time = millis();
  //check to see if increment() was called in the last 250 milliseconds
  if (button_time - last_button_time > 250)
  {
    x++;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    last_button_time = button_time;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think it's much better if you figure this yourself, since it is a very basic question. You should just substitute (or add to) the Serial.println function with a writing to the LCD. You can use the [LiquidCrystal library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystal) (click to go on the arduino reference page to see the functions and the examples). If you have problems following the examples, post a more specific question and we'll try to help..

Comment: I have attempted it but have failed :(

Comment: It keeps giving me the number 3 on the lcd

Comment: Never  mind I have done it!!! Thank you so much for the help and links :)

Comment: And now you learnt something new ;) good work, anyway :)